# Code not working to delete posts from WordPress frontend

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to allow my users to delete posts which they have created from the front end.

I understand they must have the user capability to delete posts. They are assigned the role 'author' with this capability.

I then added code which displays only if they are either

1) the author of the post or

2) have permission to edit_others_posts.

Right now, the link appears... they can click it... it asks them to confirm if they want to delete.... and it just sends them back to the home page. It doesn't actually delete. Here is the URL of the site:

https://peerunschooling.net/members/discussions/

```
<?php 

if (($post->post_author == $current_user->ID) || (current_user_can('edit_others_pages'))) { ?>
    <a onclick="return confirm('Are you SURE you want to delete this post?')" href="<?php echo get_delete_post_link( $post->ID ) ?>">delete</a>

    <?php do_action( 'gform_update_post/edit_link', array(
           'post_id' => $post->ID,
           'url' => $custom_post_edit_url
            ) ); ?>
    <?php do_shortcode('[gform_update_post_edit_link]'); ?>

<?php } ?>
```